# React + Vite App Not Loading on iOS When Wrapped with Cordova (White Screen Issue)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, cordova, vite

I'm currently working on a React project using Vite and attempting to wrap it with Cordova for mobile deployment. Everything functions correctly on Android, but when running on iOS, I encounter a white screen and the app fails to load.

**What I've Tried:**

1. Followed the standard Cordova approach: created a Cordova project, added Android and iOS platforms, moved build files to the www folder, and used cordova run .
2. Tested with a Create React App (CRA) project in the same Cordova setup, which worked fine on iOS.
3. Replaced the app's build file with a basic JavaScript file, which loaded correctly.
4. Modified the HTML to load this basic JavaScript file as type="module" (as Vite sets it), which resulted in failure.
5. Attempted to alter the Vite build process to generate a non-module JavaScript file, but this did not resolve the issue.

**Observations:**

- It seems Cordova on iOS has trouble loading files with type="module".
- Even after switching to a SystemJS-based build, the issue persisted.

**Temporary Solution:**

Successfully made it work using Capacitor instead of Cordova, but I'm interested in finding a Cordova-based solution.
Question:
Has anyone successfully integrated React, Vite, and Cordova, particularly for iOS deployment? Any insights or suggestions to resolve this module loading issue with Cordova on iOS would be greatly appreciated.

**Environment:**

- React
- Vite
- Cordova

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But while debugging I noticed that it was trying to load the assets from `file:///...`

To overcome this issue I had to set:

```
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

This will serve up your app from `app://localhost` instead of `file://`. Which for me resolved the issue.